# React-Native downgrade

Tags: version-control, react-native, downgrade, react-native-debugger

I tried using react-native-debugger for debugging my application developed in react-native. I found the react-native debugger is not working as my react-native is in version 0.63.4 and the react-native debugger will only support version till 0.62. hence they are not connecting with each other.
I just want either to downgrade my react-native to 0.62 or to upgrade react-native debugger.

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Please help me to resolve this problem as i am a newbie to this react-native.
Thank you

Comment: Why don't use https://fbflipper.com/docs/features/react-native/ ? it is working out of the box with RN 0.63 and it have the same features than react-native-debugger. You may add https://github.com/jk-gan/redux-flipper for redux debugging

Comment: Thank you for sharing Nicolas. I am learning react-native from a course pack they referred me this. But ill try using flipper and work things out.

Comment: Okay, Honestly i don't think that downgrading version is sutch a good thing. 
but if you realy need for your "course" purpose you can just create a new react native 62 project and move your src files in it. 
you will have to "configure" your project again but it's a good whay to learn ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to not use "react-native-debugger" cause downgrading react native version for this package in not a good practice.

hope you get your answer.